# How to fix 'It want to set a value in a var, but it get a Promise { <pending> }'

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

(sorry for my english but i'm learning :D)

Hey guys, i'm a beginner with node and js, and i want to create a 'getPendingKYC' function on my db class, but when i execute the function, i always receive a Promise{  }, but i want to receive the result of query directly without manage the promise with .then on my var...
I just want to have the value of the result of the function on my var outside the class when i call the function.

//

// This is the script page

```
const { Client } = require('pg');


class Db {
    constructor() {
        this.client = this.dbConnect();
    }

    dbConnect() {
        return new Client({
            user: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            host: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            database: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            password: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            port: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
        });
    }

    async getPendingKyc() {
        this.client.connect();
        let data = await this.client.query('SELECT * FROM users')
        this.client.end();
        return data.rowCount;
    };
};

const db = new Db();
let data = db.getPendingKyc();
console.log(data);
```

if i put "await" before of db.getPendingKyc() i receive the next error:

---

let data = await db.getPendingKyc();
           ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

---

if i put .then after db.getPendingKyc() i can show correctly the value, but i want to have it on a var without do this.

¿How can i do to get the value to work with him direcly on the var without handling the promise outside the class?

Answer (score 0):

When not in an async function, you can do ...

```
const db = new Db();
db.getPendingKyc().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: i know, but how can i do if i want to have directly the value in a new var, and print that like in my example.

Comment: You might need to use IIFE as 

  (async () => {
    let data = await db.getPendingKyc();
    console.log('data=',data); 
    return test1;
})();

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your function call inside async function to use await 
so your code should be like

```
(async()=>{
const db = new Db();
let data = await db.getPendingKyc();
console.log(data);
})()
```

or you can use `then` 
so you can do it like this

```
const db = new Db();
db.getPendingKyc().then((data)=>{
 console.log(data);
 }
```